# My desktop was deleted and now it cannot be installed

Tags: apt, python, 22.04

I had some problems with apt_pkg and I entered some commands that I found with Google in the terminal. I think it was about Python, because I now have a non-default Python version. My Python version is 3.11 and pip is OK. I can't use add-apt because I don't have apt_pkg and I tried to install it but it didn't work and I entered some codes like this `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`,  but they didn't work.  Can you help me install the desktop?

[image]

Comment: start again from scratch. Reinstall the OS.

Comment: No one can help unless you give specifics. "Some codes that I saw on Google" is inadequate.

Comment: Don't run random stuff from google without understanding what it does.  When you `apt remove...` look carefully at what you are removing before saying yes...make sure you aren't removing stuff you want like desktop.  Don't remove stuff you are about to reinstall.  Ever.  Use `apt install --reinstall` instead.  And never never never remove  or even change the main version of python from your system.

Comment: Did you delete or move content from `/var/lib/apt/lists/`? If so, you will need to run `sudo apt update` to repopulate it

Comment: Review your `~/.bash_history` file to discover exactly what commands you ran, and their order. [Add that information](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1458800/edit) to your question above.

Comment: Review your `/var/log/apt/history.log` file to discover exactly what packages were removed and when. Add that information, too.